# I don't understand how this function works

Tags: haskell

```
estaLivre lg pls = head [s | (l,s) <- pls, l==lg] == 0
```

This function receives two lists as parameters. The first one is the coordinates of a chair in a theater. Like `(1, 1)` row 1, column 1. `pls` is the description of the chairs in the theater. `pls` consists of the coordinates of the chair and 1 or 0, wich tells if the chair is taken (1) or if its not (0). Something like this: `pls = [((1, 1), 1), ((1, 2), 0)]` the chair `(1, 1)` is taken. The chair `(1, 2)` is not.

I didn't understand how this woks. `head` takes the first element of the list and sees if it equals to 0 (is that right?) but `s` is not the first element. So how does this work?

I've done some tests to see how this works and apparently, head takes the element that's before the '|'. In this case, 's'. One of my tests was to take the head of `[y | (x, y) <- xs, x == y^1/2]`. It returned the value of `y`. I did the same thing with `[x | (x, y) <- xs, y == x^2]` and it returned `x`. But it's still confusing to me because I was taught that head takes the first element of a list. Can someone explain this to me?

Comment: You should read about [list comprehensions](http://learnyouahaskell.com/starting-out#im-a-list-comprehension). In particular, examine what `[s | (l,s) <- pls, l==lg]` gives you -- that's the list that `head` is finding the first element of.

Answer (score 2):

Let's start with the parameters: `lg` is the position that you want to test to be free and `pls` is the list of positions, where each position is a tuple (coords,if coords are free then 0 else 1).

The list comprehension is used to pick from the list `pls` the positions that have the same coords given in input, i.e. `lg`, and then select only the second part of the tuple, that is if the position is free:

```
[s | (l,s) <- pls, l==lg]
```

Because `pls` is a list, it is possible that more than one element in it satisfies `l==lg`, for example when `pls = [((1,1),0),((1,1),0)]` the expression above will return `[0,0]`, and thus you have to use `head` to extract the first occurrence that satisfies the predicate:

```
head [s | (l,s) <- pls, l==lg]
```

This will tell you if that position is free, by returning `0`, or taken, by returning `1`, and the final test `== 0` will convert `0` or `1` into a boolean value.

As side note I would like to say that this function is terrible and unsafe, in particular because it uses `head` to extract one possible occurrence of the given coordinates. It should be rewritten to use `maps` and not `lists` and to use `bool` instead of `int` to say if the position is taken or not.

Answer (score 1):

The `head` function is defined as

```
head :: [a] -> a
head (x:xs) = x
head [] = error "Prelude.head: empty list"
```

All it does is grab the first element from the list.

What you're confused about is the list comprehension syntax.  This is a syntax that lets you write list operations very cleanly without having to resort to functions like `map`, `filter`, or list monadic syntax (that's a topic for another day).  In short, if you see something like

```
[function x | x <- someList, condition x]
```

This is broadly equivalent to

```
map function (filter condition someList)
```

Think of `<-` as iterating over each element in `someList` and assigning that value to `x`, then it checks it against a condition function `condition`, the builds a list out of it, applying `function` to each element.  This syntax is also useful if you want to iterate over multiple lists, but I'll let you play with it yourself (try out things like `[(x, y) | x <- [1..5], y <- [6..10]]` in GHCi to see what happens).

---

So in your case, you have

```
estaLivre lg pls = head [s | (l,s) <- pls, l==lg] == 0
```

If we use the rules from above, we can convert this into

```
estaLivre lg pls = head (map snd $ filter (\(l, s) -> l == lg) pls) == 0
```

This might be more obvious if the tuple wasn't pattern matched on, you could write your original function as

```
estaLivre lg pls = head [snd x | x <- pls, fst x == lg] == 0
```

So the list `[s | (l,s) <- pls, l==lg]` is going to return a list of all seat occupancies `s` for the given row/column coordinate `lg`, then `head` gets the first element out of that list, and then it's compared to `0`.